# product of two multivariate normal densities for the same vector, if one is only specified for a subset

Tags: probability-theory

A random vector x with n elements has a multivariate-normal density f(x).

Another distribution is known for m linear combinations of elements of x. The linear combinations are given in the form Ax=c+r where A is an mn matrix of constants, c is a vector of constants, and r is a vector of independent mean-zero normal-distributed variables.

What I am trying to do is, to derive a second normal density g(x) from A*x=c+r, that can be multiplied with f(x).

The first problem I have is, that m < n, so that A is not invertible.

However, can one still write x=A’c+A’r (with A’ as inverse of A) as an intermediate step (the ultimate goal is finding the expected value of the product of f(x) and g(x), for which the matrix inversion will be cancelled out by a second inversion)? Or is there an alternative way?

The second problem is, that not all elements of x will be used in the linear combinations, and hence, the vector for x derived with x=A’c+A’r will not include all elements of x.

Can one still argue that g(x) and f(x) are densities for the same vector x, and treat the product f(x)*g(x) as a product of two multivariate normal densities (and calculate the parameters accordingly, as for example in http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/2003-003.pdf)? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$, $A$, $c$, and $r$ are all already known, all you can do* is check that the density $f(x)$ is in agreement with the fact that $A\vec X=c+\vec r$.

To illustrate with the simplest relevant case, suppose $m=1$, $n=2$, and
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then $$X_1=A\begin{pmatrix}X_1\\X_2\end{pmatrix}=A\vec X=c+R$$
(where I used upper case letters for random variables and $\vec\cdot$ for vectors).

Suppose now that, to again take the simplest case,
$$
f(x_1,x_2)=(2\pi)^{-1}\exp\left(-\frac12\left(x_1^2+x_2^2\right)\right).$$
Then $c$ would have to be 0, and $R$ would have to be standard normal.

---

*Note that there's only one density for a given vector, so having both $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ and multiplying them doesn't make sense.

Comment: Still not sure what the question is. Maybe formulate it in terms of prior and posterior?

Comment: ok - yes, I felt it sounds confusing as well, have just tried to rephrase and compress  - and posted as a new question:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242612/product-of-multivariate-gaussian-densities