# Product of two densities, when one of them is "incomplete"

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

One can frequently read that the product of two multivariate Gaussian pdfs, $f_1(x)$*$f_2(x)$, is itself a Gaussian function, with parameters as defined for example in:

http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf
(section 8.1.8 page 42)

But what if the parameters (mean vector, covariance matrix) for $f_2$ are not given for all elements of $x$?  I.e. if the mean vector of $f_2$ contains values only for some of the random elements of $x$, and the $f_2$ covariance matrix - which is here assumed to be diagonal - also contains only values for this subset of the elements of $x$?  Is the product then still a Gaussian and how can the parameters be calculated?

Comment: Hint: $f_{X,Y}{x,y} = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ for _independent_ random variables (or vectors). For multivariate random variables, the mean vector is the concatenation of the constituent mean vectors while the covariance matrix is $$\Sigma = \left[\begin{matrix}\Sigma_1&\mathbf 0\\\mathbf 0& \Sigma_2\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate Thank you Dilip - yes, I think this will help...  in the meantime, I found a way for the underlying problem so both densities' covariance matrices and mean vectors contain expressions for all the elements in the vector - still working on this, though.  Hope I can come back with more clarification, soon.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate thanks again - I think I got what you are saying.  I could partition the vector $x$ into two parts, where one part, $x_a$ includes all those elements for which both $f_1$ and $f_2$ have parameters, and $x_b$ contains all the other elements.  And then multiply $f_1(x_a)$ and $f_2(x_a)$ to get f(x_a). This I would then have to concatenate with $f_1(x_b)$ to get $f(x) = f_1(x)f_2(x)$.  Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Your notation is horrendous and adds to the overall confusion. When you write $f(x) = f_1(x)f_2(x)$, the three occurrences of $x$ represent three different things. You are thus violating a basic convention in mathematics that a symbol should mean the same thing everywhere it occurs in an expression or formula.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate - thanks for your feedback!  however, I'm not sure if the notation here is that wrong.  Here x is supposed to be the same vector/set of variables, but the densities are different.  This was actually pointed out to me in an answer to an earlier question:  please have a look at the answer I got there:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221058/product-of-densities.  The references given in the question also use similar notation.  However, I'm not ruling out that I have misunderstood something.  What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

> One can frequently read that the product of two multivariate Gaussian pdfs, $f_1(x)$*$f_2(x)$, is itself a Gaussian,

This is an incorrect statement no matter how many times or in how many
different places you have read it; indeed it does not hold even for
univariate Gaussian random variables. If the link you have provided
does indeed say *exactly* what you have written, then I suggest that
you apply the instructions given by Dorothy Parker in a famous book review: "This is not a book to be put down lightly; it should be thrown
with great force."

What *is* true is that if $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* (univariate) Gaussian
random variables with densities $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$
respectively, then the product $f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ *equals* the
**joint** density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Note that the 
*joint* density is a function of *two* real variables which have
different names $x$ and $y$, and it is **not** claimed that
$f_X(x)f_Y(x)$ is a Gaussian density (note the lack of $y$).

More generally,if
$\mathbf X = (X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_m)$ and
$\mathbf Y = (Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n)$ are random vectors that are *independent* of each other and $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y$ have
multivariate Gaussian densities 
$$\begin{align}
f_{\mathbf X}(\mathbf x) &= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{m/2}\sqrt{|\operatorname{det}(\Sigma_X)|}}\exp\left(-\frac 12(\mathbf x - \mathbf m_X)\Sigma_X^{-1}
(\mathbf x - \mathbf m_X)^T\right)\\
f_{\mathbf Y}(\mathbf y) &= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}\sqrt{|\operatorname{det}(\Sigma_Y)|}}\exp\left(-\frac 12(\mathbf y - \mathbf m_Y)\Sigma_Y^{-1}
(\mathbf y - \mathbf m_Y)^T\right)
\end{align}$$
where $\Sigma_X$ and $\Sigma_Y$ are $m\times m$ and 
$n \times n$ covariance matrices, and $\mathbf m_X$ 
and $\mathbf m_Y$ are the mean vectors, of $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y$
respectively. Note that these densities are functions of $m$ and
$n$ real variables $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m)$ and
$(y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_n)$ respectively.
Then
$$f_{\mathbf X, \mathbf Y}\big ((\mathbf x, \mathbf y)\big)
= f_{\mathbf X}(\mathbf x)f_{\mathbf Y}(\mathbf y)$$
where $(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) = 
(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m, y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_n)$ is a vector
of $m+n$ real numbers. Plugging and chugging, we have that
$$\begin{align}
f_{\mathbf X, \mathbf Y}\big ((\mathbf x, \mathbf y)\big)
&= \frac{\exp\left(-\frac 12(\mathbf x - \mathbf m_X)\Sigma_X^{-1}
(\mathbf x - \mathbf m_X)^T-\frac 12(\mathbf y - \mathbf m_Y)\Sigma_Y^{-1}
(\mathbf y - \mathbf m_Y)^T\right)}{(2\pi)^{(m+n)/2}
\sqrt{|\operatorname{det}(\Sigma_X)|\cdot|\operatorname{det}(\Sigma_Y)|}}\tag{1}\\
&= \frac{\exp\left(-\frac 12(\mathbf z - \mathbf m)\Sigma^{-1}
(\mathbf z - \mathbf m)^T\right)}{(2\pi)^{(m+n)/2}
\sqrt{|\operatorname{det}(\Sigma)|}}\tag{2}
\end{align}$$
where $\mathbf z = (\mathbf x, \mathbf y) 
= (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m, y_1, \ldots, y_n)$,
$\mathbf m = (\mathbf m_X,\mathbf m_Y)$ is the mean
vector of the $(m+n)$-dimensional multivariate Gaussian vector
$\mathbf Z = (\mathbf X, \mathbf Y)$, and
$$\Sigma = \left[\begin{matrix}\Sigma_X&\mathbf 0\\\mathbf 0& \Sigma_Y\end{matrix}\right]\tag{3}$$ is the $(m+n)\times (m+n)$ covariance matrix.
The derivations are greatly simplified by observing the block
structure $(3)$ of the covariance matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your effort.  Would you mind sparing a moment to have a brief look at section 8.1.8 page 41 of "The Matrix Cookbook"?  available here:  http://www.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf and maybe also at page 200 of this source: http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RWA.pdf section products at the bottom, and further maybe here:  http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/2003-003.pdf.  This were for me the most helpful sources on that topic.

Comment: An example where this property is used is Bayesian estimation:  see page 11 of the following: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=28A2A856531E5FF9FABEC67397A87B5D?doi=10.1.1.1.2635&rep=rep1&type=pdf.  I understand what you have written in your answer, and your initial comment - although referring to densities for two different variables, was helpful and brought me on the right track to solve the problem behind the original question, and I upvoted it.

Comment: I am trying to find my misunderstanding, but I am familiar with the property you are describing for independent variables/vectors, and do not see a contradiction to the statement you claim is wrong.  I apologize if I have used improper notation and wording, the matter is still relatively new for me.  I think the best would be  if you raise your point here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221058/product-of-densities. there is an (imho) excellent answer by grand_chat, which helped me greatly to understand the cited sources.  My own intial surprise is well documented there.

Comment: maybe the distinction between "Gaussian" and "Gaussian pdf" is the crucial point here?  the quoted sources state, the product is a Gaussian, but it is not a pdf (not normalized).  In other words, it is proportional to a Gaussian pdf, and by multiplying with a normalizing constant becomes a Gaussian pdf.